# Segmentation Fault for a Program that Indexes Words from a File

Tags: c, cs50

I am getting a segmentation fault for a C program that first reads the characters of a given file, identifies words, indexes words, and prints the first word. I have been troubleshooting for a long time but cannot seem to find what the error is.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./test15 text\n");
        return 1;
    }
    char *file = argv[1];
    FILE *ptr = fopen(file, "r");
    char ch;
    int i = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int j = 0;
    char *text = malloc(sizeof(char));
    string word[k];
    while ((ch = fgetc(ptr)) != EOF)
    {
        text[i] = ch;
        if (ch == ' ')
        {
            for (int l = j; l < i; l++)
            {
                strcat(word[k], &text[l]);
            }
            k++;
            j = i;
        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("%s\n", word[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seg faults are caused by trying to access memory you're not supposed to / not allocated. I see you're creating the `word` array with a size of 0 which could definitely cause issues. When you increase `k` later on, the size of the `word` array will not increase. You're also allocating `text` the size of a char, yet you attempt to read from `text[i]` later on. These would be a good place to start.

Comment: @ZenMonkey Thank you for your insight. I modified the code by creating a non-dynamic array after counting each space between words from a file. However, the program doesn't even run properly now. I'd be grateful for some feedback on why this doesn't work, and how I should go about indexing strings from a text file. This is the link to my second post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60314857/continued-segmentation-fault-for-program-that-indexes-words-from-a-file

Comment: @lucidcloud — should you delete this post now?

Comment: Instead of deleting it, I will add a link to a better post that contains the solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60330256/program-that-indexes-words-from-a-given-file-returns-an-empty-space-when-printin/60333552?noredirect=1#comment106755978_60333552

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like @Zen said, a `SEGFAULT` will occur if you try to access a memory location you are not allowed to or not allocated.

Your program terminates just after the first iteration because `i` becomes `1` at that moment and `text[1]` becomes inaccessible because `text` was allocated the size of a single character only:
`char *text = malloc(sizeof(char));` here.

Yet, I have not checked your algorithm right now so I am only providing an initial observation. If any errors still pop up, feel free to post on this thread here.

Best.