# Continued: Segmentation fault for program that indexes words from a file

Tags: c

I am getting a segmentation fault for a program that is supposed to index words read from a file. I changed the first part of my code where I tried to create a dynamic array, realizing that arrays cannot be dynamic. Previously, I used to get a segmentation fault, but now the program compiles but doesn't even run properly. I would highly appreciate some feedback. The link to my previous post is 
[Segmentation Fault for a Program that Indexes Words from a File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60312688/segmentation-fault-for-a-program-that-indexes-words-from-a-file?noredirect=1#comment106687985_60312688)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //Check if the usage is correct
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./test15 text\n");
        return 1;
    }

    //Main program
    char *file = argv[1];
    FILE *ptr = fopen(file, "r");
    char ch;
    int i = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int j = 0;
    char *text = malloc(sizeof(char));

    while ((ch = fgetc(ptr)) != EOF)
    {
        text[i] = ch;
        if (ch == ' ')
        {
            k++;
        }
        i++;
    }

    char *word[k];
    i = 0;
    int l = 0;

    while ((ch = fgetc(ptr)) != EOF)
    {
        text[i] = ch;
        if (ch == ' ')
        {
            for (int m = j; m < i; m++)
            {
                int d = i - j;
                strncat(word[l], &text[m], d);
            }
            j = i + 1;
            l++;
        }
        i++;
        printf("%s\n", word[l]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What symptoms of "doesn't even run properly" do you observe? Imemdiate return? Endless loop? Crash? Hang?

Comment: Good style, making a new question instead of changing the old one.

Comment: You haven't fixed the error answered in your first post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Segmentation Fault for a Program that Indexes Words from a File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60312688/segmentation-fault-for-a-program-that-indexes-words-from-a-file)

Answer (score 4):

With

```
char *text = malloc(sizeof(char));
```

you allocate space for a ***single*** `char`. `text` is in essence a single-element array.

Then in the following loop, if there's more than a single byte in the file, you will go out of bounds of this single-element array. This leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Furthermore

```
char *word[k];
```

here you define an array of *uninitialized* pointers. Attempting to dereference these pointers *also* leads to *undefined behavior*.

*And* when you use a `strcat`-like function the destination pointer *must* be a pointer to a valid ***null-terminated*** string.

---

On another note, the [`fgetc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) function return an `int`. This is actually very important for the comparison against `EOF`.

Comment: IMO, unless the question asks something very unusual, pointing out UB in a program is always an explanation for why the behavior is not what the OP expects it to be.