# Program that indexes words from a given file returns an empty space when printing a certain index

Tags: c

I wrote a program that is supposed to identify any words of a given file and index each one properly so that I can print a word that is assigned a specific index. The last printf line of the code that is supposed to print the first word, however, doesn't work and returns an empty space.

*EDIT: I modified the program based on the feedback received and changed char word included in the typdef struct node into char *word and also allocated memory to it before using strcat to add letters to it. However, the program is still not working as it is supposed to be. index[0]->word is simply returning NULL, and I don't understand why it is happening. I updated the code with my recent changes. I'd be grateful for any feedback.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node
{
    char *word;
    struct node *next;
}node;

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //Check if the usage is correct
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./test15 text\n");
        return 1;
    }

    //Main program
    char *file = argv[1];
    FILE *ptr = fopen(file, "r");
    char ch;
    int i = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int j = 0;
    char *text = malloc(sizeof(char));

    while ((ch = fgetc(ptr)) != EOF)
    {
        text[i] = ch;
        if (ch == ' ')
        {
            k++;
        }
        i++;
    }

    node *index[k];

    for (int l = 0; l < k; l++)
    {
        index[l] = malloc(sizeof(node));
        index[l+1] = malloc(sizeof(node));
        index[l]->next = index[l+1];
    }

    i = 0;
    int o = 0;

    while ((ch = fgetc(ptr)) != EOF)
    {
        text[i] = ch;
        if (ch == ' ')
        {
            index[o]->word = malloc(20*sizeof(char));
            for (int n = j; n < i; n++)
            {
                //int d = i - j;
                strcat(index[o]->word, &text[n]);
            }
            j = i + 1;
            o++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("%s\n", index[0]->word);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `word` is a single `char`. You can't store a string in there (apart from the empty string).  `strncat(&index[o]->word, &text[n], d);` that is undefined behaviour as you copy more than the target memory can hold.

Comment: Instead you could do `char *word` and then use `strdup`. Or use `char word[MAX_LEN]`

Comment: @kaylum I edited the code so that word is now a string and has memory. However, whenever I try to print the index[i]->word, it doesn't print what it is supposed to. It sometimes prints a null, sometimes prints an empty space, and sometimes just gives me a segmentation fault. I looked at my code, but I am having a very hard time trying to find issues. This issue is especially difficult because the program compiles; it simply doesn't work.

Comment: @kaylum I'd be grateful for some feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program logic of attempting to be an *array of pointers* and a *linked-list* is a recipe for confusion, and prevents simply allocating for a block of `nodes` (as any reallocation would change the `->next` address held). If you declare an *array*, then `->next` is superfluous as `next = &array[n+1]` so it isn't needed if you use an array. If you want a linked-list, then forget about the array -- it is superfluous to the list. (see link to a linked-list implementation at the end)

Either way, your use of `fgetc` doesn't handle *leading* or *multiple intervening* spaces (*whitespace*). However, there is a C standard library function that does skip leading *whtiespace* and read characters until the next *whitespace* (the very simple `fscanf` with the `"%s"` *format-specifier*)

Replacing `fgetc` with `fscanf`, reduces the reading of words to:

```
#define MAXW  128
...
    char buf[MAXW];
    FILE *fp = fopen (argv[1], "r");
    ...
    while (fscanf (fp, "%127s", buf) == 1) {    /* read each word from file */
        ...
```

That greatly simplifies the logic of reading space-separated words.

If you are reading an unknown number of words of unknown length and you want to size your allocations efficiently allocating only what is needed to store each word, then your approach is the normal declare a *pointer-to-pointer* (e.g. `char **words = NULL;`), then allocate some initial number of pointers, read the word into a temporary buffer, get the length, allocate `length+1` chars of storage, copy the word to the storage and assign the starting address to the next allocated pointer. When you have used the initial number of pointers allocated, `realloc` and keep going.

Implementing that logic and tracking the available allocated number of pointers with `avail` and the used pointers with `used` and reallocating when `used == avail`, you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define WORDS   2   /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define MAXW  128

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char buf[MAXW];
    size_t  used = 0, avail = WORDS;  /* used & available (allocated) pointers */
    char **words = NULL;
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    /* allocate/validate initial avail no. of pointers */
    if ((words = malloc (avail * sizeof *words)) == NULL) {
        perror ("malloc-words");
        return 1;
    }

    while (fscanf (fp, "%127s", buf) == 1) {    /* read each word from file */
        size_t len;
        if (used == avail) {    /* realloc 2X pointers if used == avail */
            void *tmp = realloc (words, 2 * avail * sizeof *words);
            if (!tmp) { /* validate reallocation */
                perror ("realloc-words");
                break;      /* don't exit, original pointer words still valid */
            }
            words = tmp;    /* assign reallocated block of ptrs to words */
            avail *= 2;     /* update the number of pointers available */
        }
        len = strlen (buf);                         /* get word length */
        if (!(words[used] = malloc (len + 1))) {    /* allocate len + 1 chars */
            perror ("malloc-words[used]");
            break;          /* ditto */
        }
        memcpy (words[used++], buf, len + 1);       /* copy word to storage */
    }

    if (fp != stdin)   /* close file if not stdin */
        fclose (fp);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < used; i++) {             /* loop outputting words */
        printf ("words[%2zu] : %s\n", i, words[i]);
        free (words[i]);    /* free storage for words */
    }
    free (words);           /* free pointers */
}
```

If you have `strdup` available, then you can replace the manual allocation and copy above:

```
        len = strlen (buf);                         /* get word length */
        if (!(words[used] = malloc (len + 1))) {    /* allocate len + 1 chars */
            perror ("malloc-words[used]");
            break;
        }
        memcpy (words[used++], buf, len + 1);       /* copy word to storage */
```

with a simple assignment from `strdup(buf)`, but as with any function that allocates memory, you must ***check the return***:

```
       if (!(words[used] = strdup (buf))) {         /* strdup allocates - you validate */
            perror ("strdup-words[used]");
            break;
        }
        used++;
```

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/captnjack.txt
This is a tale
Of Captain Jack Sparrow
A Pirate So Brave
On the Seven Seas.
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/fscanf_words dat/captnjack.txt
words[ 0] : This
words[ 1] : is
words[ 2] : a
words[ 3] : tale
words[ 4] : Of
words[ 5] : Captain
words[ 6] : Jack
words[ 7] : Sparrow
words[ 8] : A
words[ 9] : Pirate
words[10] : So
words[11] : Brave
words[12] : On
words[13] : the
words[14] : Seven
words[15] : Seas.
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to ensure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/fscanf_words dat/captnjack.txt
==12872== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==12872== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==12872== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==12872== Command: ./bin/fscanf_words dat/captnjack.txt
==12872==
words[ 0] : This
words[ 1] : is
words[ 2] : a
words[ 3] : tale
words[ 4] : Of
words[ 5] : Captain
words[ 6] : Jack
words[ 7] : Sparrow
words[ 8] : A
words[ 9] : Pirate
words[10] : So
words[11] : Brave
words[12] : On
words[13] : the
words[14] : Seven
words[15] : Seas.
==12872==
==12872== HEAP SUMMARY:
==12872==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12872==   total heap usage: 23 allocs, 23 frees, 5,988 bytes allocated
==12872==
==12872== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==12872==
==12872== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==12872== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

If you want a **linked-list** and want to get rid of the array, then see [Singly Linked List of Strings With Sorted Insertion](https://pastebin.com/PechfyQa) for an implementation.

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I just have a few questions. In if ((words = malloc (avail * sizeof *words)) == NULL)
    {
        perror ("malloc-words");
        return 1;
    }
Shouldn't avail * sizeof *words also be NULL, since avail == 2 and char **words == NULL before this if statement?

Comment: Also, I would be grateful if you could explain the logic of 
if (used == avail) {    /* realloc 2X pointers if used == avail */
            void *tmp = realloc (words, 2 * avail * sizeof *words);
            if (!tmp) { /* validate reallocation */
                perror ("realloc-words");
                break;      /* don't exit, original pointer words still valid */
            }
I think I understand the realloc part but I don't get the if (used == avail) part.

Comment: `words = malloc (avail * sizeof *words)) == NULL)` allocates `avail` (`2`) pointers. `words` is `char**`, so `*words` is `char*`, so `sizeof *words` is `sizeof(a_pointer)`  (if you always allocated with the dereferenced pointer for your *typesize*, you'll never get it wrong). `words` points to a block of memory of `avail` pointers. `used` is the number of pointers you have assigned storage to (for a word). So you have your block of memory holding pointers (`words`) and then a block of memory to store each string in assigned to each pointer (`words[n]`).

Comment: Here `used` tracks the number of pointers you have assigned storage for a word to. `avail` tells you how many pointers can fit in the storage you assigned to `words`. When `used == avail` you are out of pointers, so you `realloc (words, ...)` to have storage for twice as many pointers as you do now (2X the number of pointers, e. g. `2 * avail * sizeof *words)`). That's why if the `realloc` succeeds, you assign the newly allocated block (that `realloc` copies the original pointers to) to `words` (e.g. `words = tmp;`), and update the number available, (e.g. `avail *= 2;`) Standard scheme.

Comment: So bottom line `used` tracks the number of pointers you have *used*. `avail` tracks the number of pointers you have allocated (*available* pointers). When `used == avail`, you have used all your available pointers, so you must `realloc` more pointers. And you always check if you have a pointer available before you attempt to allocate storage for a string and assign it to the next pointer -- which is why `if (used == allocated)` appears near the top of the read loop.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help. It took me quite a while to understand the code, but I definitely learned a lot from this. I was initially confused where used is actually incremented, but I figured that it is done during memcpy. I also found out that replacing words[used++] with words[used += 1] gives me a segmentation fault. That's how I figured that used++ is done after memcpy.

Comment: Excellent work. C is largely about putting your accounts hat on and accounting for each byte of memory you use and keeping track of where it all lives. Digesting dynamic allocation and reallocation opens up a whole new range of possibilities of what you can do with the language -- limited only by the virtual memory available on your hardware. Good luck with your coding.